# How to show or create a 360 Rotating dial in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Are there any `Widget` in `Qt` by which a 360 rotating dial can be displayed? I want to show just like below. But there would be a indicator. If the user rotate this indicator, current angular position of indicator in degree will be displayed in a `QLineEdit`. I have already searched by using `QDial`, but unfortunately didn't get any function for this. [image]

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there isn't. Why don't you just go ahead and create your custom widget?

Answer (score 0):

Qt's `QDial` is merely a wrapper around a *platform-dependend fancy* dial.

Try `QwtDial` from the Qwt library at http://qwt.sourceforge.net/ for more control over the appearance and behaviour.